# Postgres not responding with high waiting time

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using Django with Postgres.
My site servers half a million pages without any issue and everything works fine.

However I am using an API system and it works like below:

> First party calls my site with API, my site gets data from third
>   website using API. My site extracts some data and pass it to First
>   party. It works perfectly. In this cycle I have to check my Postgres
>   whether data is already present or not.

Everything works fine. But if third party API does not respond or there is any server issue with third party it takes long time to respond with 404 error, my postgres just dies and I have to run `service postgresql restart` command everytime to site work.

What could be the issue? How do I check why Postgres is dying?

Comment: "But if third party API does not respond or there is any server issue with third party it takes long time to respond with 404 error, my postgres just dies and I have to run service postgresql restart command everytime to site work." How is the code implemented to query the third party API? And doesn't configurating a timeout work or isnt it possible with that framework?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, although a guess, is that your code is locking the database table while the 3rd party API call is made. This will prevent other updates occurring while waiting.

This wouldn't explain why you would need to restart the Postgres server, the lock should be released after the 3rd party API call times out.

It might help to add to your question the code that deals with checking whether the data is already present in the db, calling the remote API, and finally updating the database with new data.

Comment: I think the OP is just *leaking* sessions.